# How to mount an Azure 'App Service Folder' to a docker container?

Tags: azure, docker

Locally I start the container with 
`docker run -it -p 80:5000 --name myApp -v P:\myPath\myData:/myData`

How do I mount an app service folder from azure?

[image: App Service Folders]

Comment: I cannot understand your question clearly. What do you mean an app service folder from azure? And where do you want to mount?

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt the Dockerfile with the following line:

```
# this map's the azure App Service folder to the container.
RUN ln -s /home/myData /myDataOnTheContainer
```

And the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` setting in the application settings must be set to `true`.